# how to solve this logarithamic term? $a^{\log_{\frac1a}{\frac12}}$

Tags: logarithms

the question : $$a^{\log_{\frac1a}{\frac12}}$$
relevant equation : $$a^ {\log_a(x)} = x$$
$$\log_{c^m} (y) =\frac1m \log_c{(y)}$$ 
my try at it :
I first changed the base into a by multiplying the log part by $(-1)$.  the answer was $a^{ - \log_a{\frac12}}.$ this is equal to $\dfrac{a^1}{\log_a\left(\frac12\right)}$. please help me after that.

Comment: Hi Esha;I think you need to develop some writing skills before posting a question

Comment: I am also new but that's what the tour page says

Comment: Check out the following link for math formatting tips: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thanx for showing me this.  its really a huge help.  do i need to repost this question again?

Comment: please pardon me and help me in this question .  ill try my best in the future ones

Comment: Do you mean $a^{\log_{\frac{1}{a}}\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: thanx for formatting it.  i m finally able to figure out the answer.  i was making a silly mistake all this while.

Comment: what should i start the formatting with? i mean to say do i hav to write a head, body and end just like in programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: $2.$

Proof: Let $z =  \log_{1/a}(1/2) = \frac{\log_a (1/2)}{\log_a (1/a)} = - \log_a (1/2).$

Then $a^z = a^{- \log_a (1/2)} =$ $\frac {1} {a^{\log_a (1/2)}} =$ $\frac {1} {1/2} = 2.$

Comment: My edit: You forgot the dollar signs and had 1 missing brace bracket. And I separated the lines.